# 8GB of ram OK for FreeNAS ZFS 6TBx2 in Raid 1

Tags: truenas

Is 8gb's of ram ok for FreeNAS ZFS 6TBx2 in Raid 1 ?

Or does it have to be 16gb's ?

I only use this for home backup: images/videos/plex.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8GB of RAM would be fine.

Why are you asking? Do you have a particular concern or reason to think there would be a problem?

Comment: Hi ewwhite, thanks for the help. Yes, because it's 6TBx2 so it's 12TB's total. So I thought it has to be 16GB's ram

Comment: No, that's not really the way to manage or measure your needs. RAM in ZFS is really used for read caching. For the workload your'e described, having more RAM is not critical.